# Substring (pyspark.sql.Column.substr) with restrictions

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a code for example C78907. I want to split it:

```
C78     # level 1
C789    # Level2
C7890   # Level 3
C78907  # Level 4
```

So far what I m using:

```
Df3 = Df2.withColumn('Level_One', concat(Df2.code.substr(1, 3)))
Df4 = Df3.withColumn('Level_two', concat(Df3.code.substr(1, 4)))
Df5 = Df4.withColumn('Level_theree', concat(Df4.code.substr(1, 5)))
Df6 = Df5.withColumn('Level_four', concat(Df5.code.substr(1, 6)))
```

The issue is when looking to the results, the codes of level four ( supposed to be 6 components) might contain codes from level one or two or three.

```
721 7213    7213    7213
758 7580    7580    7580
724 7242    7242    7242
737 7373    73730   73730
789 7895    78959   78959
V06 V061    V061    V061
381 3810    38100   38100
```

Ideally a restriction could be useful. I mean:

- For level one keep only 3 components.
- For level two 4 components and NOT LESS.
- For level three 5 components and NOT LESS.
- For level four 6 components and NOT LESS.
- If the required number of components don't exist then put `null` instead of imputing with the previous one.

The desired output :

```
Initial_code   level1  level2   level3   level4        
 7213           721    7213     null      null
 7580           758    7580     null      null
 7242           724    7242     null      null
 73730          737    7373     73730     null
 38100D         381    3810     38100     38100D
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49432950/edit) your question and add it? It would also be helpful if you could also provide a sample dataframe: [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output by using [`pyspark.sql.Column.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.when) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.length()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.length). When creating the column, check if the substring will have the correct length. If it does not, set the column to `None` using [`pyspark.sql.functions.lit()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit).

For example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn('Level_One', f.when(
        f.length(f.col('code').substr(1, 3)) == 3,
        f.col('code').substr(1, 3)
    ).otherwise(f.lit(None)))\
    .withColumn('Level_Two', f.when(
        f.length(f.col('code').substr(1, 4)) == 4,
        f.col('code').substr(1, 4)
    ).otherwise(f.lit(None)))\
    .withColumn('Level_Three', f.when(
        f.length(f.col('code').substr(1, 5)) == 5,
        f.col('code').substr(1, 5)
    ).otherwise(f.lit(None)))\
    .withColumn('Level_Four', f.when(
        f.length(f.col('code').substr(1, 6)) == 6,
        f.col('code').substr(1, 6)
    ).otherwise(f.lit(None)))\
    .show()
```

Output:

```python
+------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
|  Code|Level_One|Level_Two|Level_Three|Level_Four|
+------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
|  7213|      721|     7213|       null|      null|
|  7580|      758|     7580|       null|      null|
|  7242|      724|     7242|       null|      null|
| 73730|      737|     7373|      73730|      null|
|38100D|      381|     3810|      38100|    38100D|
+------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: **Clarification**: the `otherwise(f.lit(None))` is not needed here as `when` will return `null` by default if the condition is not met.